# Speaker draws way more peak current than RMS calculations would imply, how do I deal with that?

Tags: power-supply, h-bridge, speakers

So, for a project I'm working on, I'm trying to drive a small-ish speaker (Visaton SL87XA, 4 ohm version) using a FET H-bridge driven rail-to-rail from a RE46C100 horn driver chip in what's effectively a Class D situation.  Based on the speaker nominal impedance (and the typical impedance graph, which doesn't dive below Znom at any point), at the frequency of interest, I should be getting 9V/4ohm = 2.25A of RMS load current, which also should match the power supply current of my output stage as a hard-switched stage doesn't have quiescent bias currents.

However, when I try to power the circuit up, it exhibits a far higher current draw than that, around 7.75A, which is far outside my power budget (and enough to cause the surrogate supply I've been testing with to shut down).  Why would this be so?

The only thing I've been able to think of is that the speaker load is drawing an excess of reactive power since the DC resistance of the voice coil is about 4 ohms as well; however, adding a 3.9ohm/22uF Zobel network across the speaker leads does not change what is happening.  And note that while this is not a RMS current, it isn't shoot-through either (its "peak" in the longer term sense, not instantaneous current spikes alone.)

Should I be taking a different approach to correcting this situation, or where is my reasoning wrong?  (Note that I don't have any bulk decoupling on the H-bridge stage for now -- if that's my problem, though, I can try whacking capacitors in to address that.)  See the schematic and scope shot (100mV/A on channel 1 as that's a reading across a current shunt) below for details.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f54RH4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: scope shot of what I can get of the circuit operating]

Comment: Please provide a schematic.

Comment: Please provide an **actual** schematic - show how you drive the gates, if there are any gate resistors, what exactly the gate drivers are, etc. All those details are what make this circuit not work.

Comment: The gate driver is direct from the chip I mentioned -- there is nothing but wire between the driver outputs and the FET gates

Comment: What are the scope channels connected to?  Where is the current shunt located in the schematic?  Has the current shunt been compensated for stray inductance?  Does the reading from the current shunt agree with the output current reading of the 9V PSU?  What happens when you connect the speaker to a PSU directly - it should appear to be a pure resistance of 4Ω, but apply a low voltage, say, 1V to be cautious - and read the datasheet before doing this, some speakers must **never** be connected to DC.

Comment: @FabioBarone -- the 9V PSU doesn't have an ammeter :P.  I have the scope on the supply, on the shunt (low side measurement in the ground going back to the PSU), and have also been measuring various other waveforms (gate drive, as well as output current using a similar shunt in the output).  The shunt is a COTS noninductive 0.1ohm resistor.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I have to repeat what others have already said: please provide an actual schematic, and identify on that schematic where the scope probes are placed.  Otherwise we will be guessing.  If I was you, I would be trying to determine (a) is this excessive current flow real, and (b) is it passing through the speaker or something else.  A simple CT (current transformer) connected to your scope that monitors the current passing through the speaker would answer both questions very quickly.    Cheers.

Comment: @FabioBarone -- best I can tell from a differential measurement (scope probes on either side of a 0.1ohm shunt in series with the speaker), not all of the current in the supply is flowing through the speaker, but it's a very rough measurement (math mode on noisy signals on my scope is not fun)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  You're wasting your time trying to do differential measurement that way - too much noise.  Just get yourself a cheap CT, 100 or 200:1 and put a burden resistor on it (follow manufacturers instructions) and pass a wire through its hole.  That will give you a good reading.  Here is an example from Mouser, many other OEMs make similar, cost is less than $3.  Mouser PN:  
580-56T200C

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your H-bridge is home-grown, the usual culprit is called "shoot-through (or shoot-thru)". Basically, one side of the bridge won't be completely turned off when the other side turns onm and you get a big ol' slug of current. As Earl 7 has asked, a schematic is a must.

Comment: I still get excess current flow with the JP open (i.e. the bridge in a static state) so I'm pretty sure its _not_ a shoot through problem

Comment: OK, now that you have a schematic, your next steps are simple. Are HS and HB at Vcc and Vss (or vice versa)? If yes, one or more of your FETS is bad or misconnected. if no, your driver chip is bad. The fact that you are getting 7+ amps from a 9-volt source means the load is not involved. The impedances are too big. That leaves your bridge. Either M1/M2 or M3/M4, or both are both conducting.  You can have a failed-short FET, or a conductor bridge, or improper gate drive, and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

**When debugging such circuits, never use an actual speaker! You'll blow it! Use a dummy load first, and only once the circuit works, substiute a speaker.**

It's a common problem. Mosfets are not "ideal" switches (and neither are bipolar transistors!) - they don't read the designer's mind. They can be anything. They must be **configured** to be "ideal" voltage-controlled switches.

> FET H-bridge in what's effectively a Class D situation

That's your intention, but the parts don't know that :)

The way you configured them makes them not really act the way you want. Most likely, one of the mosfets in each half-bridge is switched ON, while the other is partially switched ON.

That's why without seeing the **complete** schematic of your circuit, it's impossible to tell what exactly is wrong.

You should start debugging by replacing the speaker by a resistor, and setting the driver to a fixed state (0Hz fixed logic state instead of 1kHz on input). Then measure what those mosfets *actually* do, vs. what you *think* they should be doing. That should shed some light on what's going on.

Had you provided a complete schematic, it'd have been reasonably simple to tell what's wrong, but as you didn't, we can only guess. Although the guesses are probably pretty good :)

If you asked me to put such a circuit together quickly, here's what I'd do - it's not the only way to do it, but I happen to have all the parts available, so that's how it'd go:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIEhix.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It'll work with supply voltages up to 15V, and shoot-through is impossible by design. For inductive loads a Zobel network is required, otherwise inductive kickback will destroy the mosfets during the idle state when all switches are off.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it's a static gate drive problem now that I'm looking at it (nothing to do with shoot through).  Thanks for the advice regarding the speaker, by the way -- thank gosh I ordered a surplus of 3.9ohm power resistors!